# How to Highlight the same Range using Find.HitHighlight in VSTO?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm trying to highlight the same Range using the following function,

```
range.Find.HitHighlight(range.Text.Substring(0, range.Text.Length));
```

But when I do this MS Word gives a message saying that "Word has reached the end of the Document. Do you want to continue from the beginning?" If I select "Yes" it works. But every time this code runs it gives the same message. I'm looking into how I can do the Highlight without the message box.

I've initially used the following snippet to highlight,

```
range.HighlightColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdYellow
```

In this approach it actually alters the original document.

Therefore I've tried using the `HitHighlight` function to do the highlight since it does not create any permanent Highlights.

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2):

I was wanting something similar. This is a partial answer.
I found this [similar question on msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/600f071c-5071-4d88-bdec-71ae6a3a4719/wdfindwrapwdfindcontinue-how-to-supress-beginningend-of-file-dialog?forum=vsto), and the solution was to use the Find.HitHighlight() call from "Application.Selection or Doc.Content".

Now, I wasn't able to get it to work from Application.Selection, but I did from Doc.Content:

```
myrange.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Find.HitHighlight( myrange.Text.Substring( 0, myrange.Text.Length ) );
```

Unfortunately, this highlights EVERY match in the document. Will see if I can find any other way. But this seems like the only one so far.

<s>OR, how about adding some unique text at beginning of range, doing search, and then removing the text?</s> BAD idea, didn't work.